# C text file to struct, array, then out

Tags: c, struct, text-files, readfile

I am trying to take a simple text file of book information and store it into an array of structs. I am just learning C compared to Java or C# and am a little confused.

I know that it has to do with how I write the code

My text file is:

```
Magician:Apprentice
RaymondE.Feist 
Spectra(January1,1994) 
5.02 
0553564943 
512 
1 
Magician:Master 
RaymondE.Feist 
Spectra(January1,1994) 
7.99 
0553564935 
499 
1
```

Then I have my code, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I know it has to do with the while(fgets(line... I know how to display all of the text, I am just having issues storing the text into a struct properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct book{

char title[100];
char author[100];
char publisher[100];
float price;
char isbn[100];
int pages;
int copies;
} Book;

int main( void )
{

//addInventory( "Magician: Apprentice", "Raymond E. Feist",     5.02, "0553564943", 512, 1 );

//Book myBook = { "Magician: Apprentice", "Raymond E. Feist", "unknown", 5.02, "0553564943", 512, 1 };

//addInventory( myBook );

   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

  printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
  gets(file_name);

  fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

  if( fp == NULL )
  {
  perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  //printf("The contents of %s file are :", file_name);

 /*while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
  printf("%c",ch);*/


    char line[9001];
    char *item;
    int reccount = 0;
    int k;
    int maxEntries = 100;



    while (fgets(line,9000,fp)) {
            printf("%s",line);


            item = strtok(line,"");
            strcpy(inventory[reccount].title,item);
            printf("1");

            item = strtok(line,"");
            strcpy(inventory[reccount].author,item);
            printf("2");

            item = strtok(line,"");
            strcpy(inventory[reccount].publisher,item);

            item = strtok(line,"");
            inventory[reccount].price = atof(item);

            item = strtok(line,"");
            strcpy(inventory[reccount].isbn,item);

            item = strtok(line,"");
            inventory[reccount].pages = atoi(item);

            item = strtok(line,"");
            inventory[reccount].copies = atoi(item);


            //printf("%s\n",inventory[reccount].publisher);
            reccount++;
            }



    fclose(fp);

printf("My Inventory:\n");  
int i;
for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    printf( "Title:\t\"%s\"\n", inventory[i].title );
    printf( "Author:\t%s\n", inventory[i].author );
    printf( "Publisher:\t%s\n", inventory[i].publisher );
    printf( "Price:\t$%.02f\n", inventory[i].price );
    printf( "ISBN:\t%s\n", inventory[i].isbn );
    printf( "Pages:\t%d\n", inventory[i].pages );
    printf( "Copies:\t%d\n", inventory[i].copies );
}

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Note that a new-style ISBN is just 13 digits; the old ones were 10 digits.  Using 100 to store the ISBN is in no danger of overflow, but it wastes 86 bytes per book.  The formatting shown for author name (in particular) and publisher (which seems to include date of publication) has unusual formatting, with no spaces separating parts of the names.  I'm glad I don't have to write the code to split `RaymondE.Feist` into first name, initial, last name (dealing with names like: `DorothySayers` — no middle initial; `MacFarlaneMcDonald` — no middle initial, multiple capitals; etc.).

Comment: `char line[9001];` , then use `fgets(line,9001,fp)` - there is no `-1`, `fgets` accounts for the *nul-terminator*.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a problem with fgets.
First of all, `fgets` reads a line of text from a file, and `strtok` splits a string using a delimiter. You probably want to format your file like this:

```
Magician:Apprentice RaymondE.Feist Spectra(January1,1994) 5.02 0553564943 512 1 
Magician:Master RaymondE.Feist Spectra(January1,1994) 7.99 0553564935 499 1
```

Then use `" "` as a delimiter. Second of all, after the first time you use `strtok`, pass `NULL` in instead of `line`. You could do something like this:

```
item = strtok(line," ");
strcpy(inventory[reccount].title,item);

item = strtok(NULL," ");
strcpy(inventory[reccount].author,item);

item = strtok(NULL," ");
strcpy(inventory[reccount].publisher,item);

item = strtok(NULL," ");
inventory[reccount].price = atof(item);

item = strtok(NULL," ");
strcpy(inventory[reccount].isbn,item);

item = strtok(NULL," ");
inventory[reccount].pages = atoi(item);

item = strtok(NULL," ");
inventory[reccount].copies = atoi(item);
```

You could also use another delimiter (like `;` so that you can have spaces in the author's name), and then you could format your file like this:

```
Magician:Apprentice;Raymond E. Feist;Spectra(January1,1994);5.02;0553564943;512;1 
Magician:Master;Raymond E. Feist;Spectra(January1,1994);7.99;0553564935;499;1
```

Also `count` and `inventory` both aren't defined. You could do this (before the `while(fgets...)` loop):

```
int count = 2;
Book* inventory = malloc(count*sizeof(Book));
```

Or if you want to be able to have different sized files, just count the number of lines, and then close and reopen the file:

```
int count = 0;
while (fgets(line,9000,fp)) count++;
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
Book* inventory = malloc(count*sizeof(Book));
```

**Edit**: To keep the file format the way it is, you'll need 7 calls to `fgets` for each book. Unfortunately, `fgets` includes the newline, so you'll need to strip it with `strtok`

```
int count = 0;
while (fgets(line,9000,fp)) count++;
count = count / 7;
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
Book* inventory = malloc(count*sizeof(Book));
int i;

int reccount;
for (reccount = 0; reccount < count; reccount++){


    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    item = strtok(line, "\n");
    strcpy(inventory[reccount].title,item);

    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    item = strtok(line, "\n");
    strcpy(inventory[reccount].author,item);

    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    item = strtok(line, "\n");
    strcpy(inventory[reccount].publisher,item);

    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    inventory[reccount].price = atof(line);

    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    item = strtok(line, "\n");
    strcpy(inventory[reccount].isbn,item);

    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    inventory[reccount].pages = atoi(line);

    fgets(line,9000,fp);
    inventory[reccount].copies = atoi(line);


}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: There's truth in this.  I'm not sure about the proposed reformatting of the data; I'd prefer to see separate calls to `fgets()` for each line of data — seven calls per book.  The `strtok(line, "")` with an empty set of delimiters is a degenerate case; the first occurrence of any of the delimiters is the `'\0'` at the end of the input string. You're right that if you're splitting a line with `strtok()`, you call it once with the start pointer and then with NULL thereafter. It's better to use `strtok_r()` (POSIX) or `strtok_s()` (nominally C11, but mainly Microsoft) rather than plain `strtok()`.

Comment: The file does have to stay in that format, I know I am not doing the greatest on memory allocation, but this is just until I get it working correctly. I get what your saying about the degenerate case, I am still not sure how to store the data in the struct. With the way this is setup is sets inventory[0].title, author, publisher (etc...) to the first line, then it goes through and sets inventory[1] to the second line. How do I get each line to be proper?

Comment: I did try using "\n" as a delimiter but it didn't work. It could be something I was doing wrong though.